# MYSql REGEXP not matching Mixed Case

Tags: mysql, case-insensitive

I am having an issue with MYSql and it handling regexp searching.  Currently I have an address table that had an error and was removing spaces from the address field (varchar field).  To correct it, I am trying to find affected records that I can identify where proper capitalization was used by using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM useraddress u 
WHERE u.address1_vc REGEXP ("([a-z]+[A-Z]+)")
```

Sample Records:

```
22431 Maple Dr
3640CubscoutRd
6432 14th Ave
1133W.WashingtonPL
7920 Glambury Court
```

Expected Results:

```
3640CubscoutRd
1133W.WashingtonPL
```

The problem is that it is returning all records.  Why is it doing that and how do I form a query that will work?

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL is case-insensitive by default. You need to declare the table or column to use a case-sensitive collation.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?  Any links or suggestions?

Comment: Did you see the link at the top, after "The question already has an answer here:"?

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance and humbly accept your pointing out of such ignorance.